# Do we need to explicitly call a "return;" in a constructor? If Yes Then Why, I need a complete reason behind this

Tags: constructor

Do we need to explicitly call a "return;" in a constructor? If Yes Then Why, I need a complete reason behind this.

I am working in PHP but I would like to know how this concept works in others as well?

Comment: Why do you need a "complete reason" behind this, and what counts?  Also, you've listed three different languages.  These are all very different languages, and so the reasons/rationales might vary between languages.  You may be better off asking this as three separate questions.

Comment: No. I am yet to see any language that requires me to explicitly state 'return;' in the constructor. For some sort of flow-control, you are allowed to do that, but no, I haven't seen it as a strict requirement.

Comment: Did you think to ... you know, try it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call return explicitly in any of those languages.  It is implicit at the end of the function/method body.

If you call return before the end of the body of code, you can prevent anything else from running.  But you don't want to leave the object in an inconsistent state.  Instead throw an exception for an error case.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a return call in a Java constructor.